# Error in gradle when implement hilt library in android

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, dagger-2, dagger-hilt

I am trying to implement hilt in android studio version `2020.1.1 Canary 1` but I get this error in gradle

```
Unable to find method ''void com.android.build.api.extension.AndroidComponentsExtension$DefaultImpls.androidTests$default(com.android.build.api.extension.AndroidComponentsExtension, com.android.build.api.extension.VariantSelector, kotlin.jvm.functions.Function1, int, java.lang.Object)''
'void com.android.build.api.extension.AndroidComponentsExtension$DefaultImpls.androidTests$default(com.android.build.api.extension.AndroidComponentsExtension, com.android.build.api.extension.VariantSelector, kotlin.jvm.functions.Function1, int, java.lang.Object)'

Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)

Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.

Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)
Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.

In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.
```

Here's the `build.gradle` level project

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_version = '1.0.0-beta07'
        kotlin_version = "1.4.32"
        lifecycle_version = "2.3.1"
        hilt_version = '2.35'
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0-alpha01'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:$hilt_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and `build.gradle` level module

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id("kotlin-kapt")
    id("kotlin-parcelize")
    id("dagger.hilt.android.plugin")
}

android {

    compileSdk 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.android.gymexercisestracker"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
        useIR = true
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
        dataBinding true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion compose_version
        kotlinCompilerVersion '1.4.32'
    }


}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.0-alpha08'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_version"

    // Coroutines
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.5.0'

    //Android Room
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.4.0-alpha02"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:2.4.0-alpha02"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.4.0-alpha02"


    implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$hilt_version")
    kapt("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:$hilt_version")


}
```

and `gradle-wrapper.properties`

```
#Wed May 26 14:56:53 EET 2021
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0.2-bin.zip
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
```

I tried to Clear cache and restart but same problem

Comment: [this solution work with me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70584130/5112812)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same issue the answer from GitHub fixed it for me. link
[dagger github](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/2631#issuecomment-844896660)

Edit your project level build.gradle

Before

```
   buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath ClassPaths.gradlePlugin
        classpath ClassPaths.kotlinPlugin
        classpath Libs.Hilt.gradlePlugin
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0-alpha01'
}
}
```

After

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url  "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"
            content {
                includeModule("com.google.dagger", "hilt-android-gradle-plugin")
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
      classpath ClassPaths.gradlePlugin
      classpath ClassPaths.kotlinPlugin
      classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:HEAD-SNAPSHOT"
      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0-alpha01'

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that solves my problem. I have also added     `includeModule("com.google.dagger", "hilt-android-compiler")`

Answer (score 0):

This is weird issue even i faced, i solved it by making sure
these 2 dependencies version in **Build.gradle(app)** matches, hopefully this helps you as well

```
 implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.31-alpha"
 kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.31-alpha"
```

Here is my full dependency list for hilt
Build.gradle(app)

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
id 'kotlin-android'
id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
id 'kotlin-kapt'
id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
 }

dependencies {
//Dagger - Hilt
implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.31-alpha"
kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.31-alpha"
implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:1.0.0-alpha03"
kapt "androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0"
 }
```

build.gradle(project)

```
  dependencies {
  classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.28.3-alpha"
  }
```

Comment: All of the `com.google.dagger:hilt-android`, `hilt-android-compiler` and `hilt-android-gradle-plugin` should be the same version: 1. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.dagger/hilt-android-compiler, 2. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.dagger/hilt-android, 3.https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.dagger/hilt-android-gradle-plugin